# Rubyで繰り返しプロセス間通信したい

Tags: ruby

```
require 'thread'
require 'time'
require 'find'

read, write = IO.pipe

# 子プロセス処理
fork do
  testArray = Array.new
  inArray = {
      :id                 => 1000,
      :type               => "A"
  }
  testArray << inArray
  testArray << inArray

  # 子プロセスで読み出さないのでクローズ
  read.close
  loop do
      str = Marshal.dump(testArray)
      write.puts str
#      write.close
      sleep 5
  end

  write.close
end

# 親プロセス処理
# 親から書き込まないのでクローズ
write.close
Thread.new do
  loop do
    read.read
    result = Marshal.load(message)
  end

end

# プロセス処理終了待ち
Process.waitall
```

forkを勉強中です。
子プロセスから親プロセスにデータを渡したいと思っています。
親側でIO.pipeを作成し、子でシリアライズしたデータを親に繰り返し送ろうとしています。
繰り返し（loop do）処理がない場合、write.closeを子でおこなうことで
親側で値を取得できました。
繰り返し通知したい場合、「write.close」を行うと「write.puts」でエラーとなるため、
「write.close」をコメントアウトすると、「read.read」ができない状態となったため、
子プロセスの処理を

```
  read.close
  loop do
      str = Marshal.dump(testArray)
      write.puts str + 'end'★
      sleep 5
  end
```

親プロセス処理を

```
  loop do
    read.read
    while message = read.gets('end')★
      message.delete('end')★
      results = Marshal.load(message)
    end
  end
```

このようにしたところ、
子からの書込み１回目は成功し、
二回目は、以下まではくるももの、 Marshal.load以降が処理されません。
message.delete('end')★

書込みや読み込みを繰り返し実施する場合、そもそもこのような作りではないのでしょうか？

Comment: puts を使っていますので、`read.gets("end\n", chomp: true)` とすると良いのではないでしょうか。この場合、`message.delete('end')` は不要になります(蛇足ですが、`delete` ではなく `message.slice!('end')` かと)。また、親プロセス側の `read.read` も不要かと思います。

Comment: シリアライズされたデータはバイナリですので、送信データの長さ(バイト長) + シリアライズデータの方が良いかと思います。https://paiza.io/projects/e/fV059c6YMuiay9wT7bxjwA

Comment: metropolis さまのご助言通り送信データの長さ(バイト長) + シリアライズデータで試したところうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @metropolis よろしければ、コメントの内容を回答へ転記いただけますか？

Comment: 「Rubyのプロセス間で繰り返し通信をする簡単な方法が欲しい」というご質問であれば、drubyという古典的な手段があります。ご存知かも知れませんし、質問の趣旨とは違うかもしれませんが、念のため。

Answer (score 1):

puts を使っていますので、`read.gets("end\n", chomp: true)` とすると良いのではないでしょうか。この場合、`message.delete('end')` は不要になります(蛇足ですが、`delete` ではなく `message.slice!('end')` かと)。また、親プロセス側の `read.read` も不要かと思います。

シリアライズされたデータはバイナリですので、送信データの長さ(バイト長) + シリアライズデータの方が良いかと思います。

**コードのサンプル:**
https://paiza.io/projects/e/fV059c6YMuiay9wT7bxjwA

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50061/ruby%e3%81%a7%e7%b9%b0%e3%82%8a%e8%bf%94%e3%81%97%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e9%96%93%e9%80%9a%e4%bf%a1%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment52215_50061) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*